# How can I make a for loop that creates an array from 2 columns from different excel files?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

I've been trying to learn python coming from MATLAB and I've been struggling with creating for loops. I have around 10 excel files (.csv) with 2 columns of CURR and VOLT. I'd like to be able to quickly make a vector (or are they called arrays?) of CURR and VOLT for all the excel files.

Here is what I'm currently using:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
blue = pd.read_csv("blue.csv", usecols = ['Volt','Curr'])
blueX=blue['Curr']
blueY=blue['Volt']
plt.plot(blueX,blueY, 'r', label='Zinc')
plt.title('Zinc')
plt.gca().legend()
plt.xlabel('Current [A]')
plt.ylabel('Voltage [V]')
```

How could I streamline this into a forloop for all of the colors?
This is what I have started but I'm stuck on what a dict is and how I can call values from it. I'd like to make X and Y arrays/vectors similar to my code above if possible. Or if there's a better way of doing this I'd love to learn.

```
files = ['BLUE' , 'BLUE.REV', 'GREEN', 'GREEN.REV', 'NITRO', 'PURPLE', 'PURPLE.REV', 'RED','RED.REV','SAND','YELLOW.REW','YELLW']
for i in files:
    data[i]=pd.read_csv(i+".csv", usecols = ['VOLT', 'CURR'])
```

Comment: What is the problem?? I could not understand. The code is running well. Just pay attention to uppercase and lowercase letters for `usecols`. In your bigger code body `['Volt','Curr']` is used but in another one `['VOLT', 'CURR']` is used.

Comment: For getting access to values of the dictionary you can use `*data.values()` and using index for it e.g. `print([*data.values()][0])`.

Answer (score 0):

In your example the "data" variable has to be created before insert any value to it. You can create an empty list:

```
data = []
```

And after in every loop you can append the pandas DataFrame to that list:

```
files = ['BLUE' , 'BLUE.REV', 'GREEN', 'GREEN.REV', 'NITRO', 'PURPLE', 'PURPLE.REV', 'RED','RED.REV','SAND','YELLOW.REW','YELLW']
for i in files:
    data.append(pd.read_csv(i+".csv", usecols = ['VOLT', 'CURR']))
```

With this you will have a list "data" that contains all the data that you extract from your files and you can access it with the indexes, for example data[0] corresponds to the 'BLUE' variables, data[1] the 'BLUE.REV' variables and so on.

This is only one way to make it.